# Objective-C, C multiple equality signs in one if

Tags: objective-c, c

i did wrote a statement

```
if (sample.value > shortAverage > shortWithoutFirstAverage > longAverage) {
```

And expected the sample.value > longAverage

but this does not work and it can happen that sample.value < longAverage

```
(lldb) p (sample.value > shortAverage > shortWithoutFirstAverage > longAverage)
(bool) $13 = true
(lldb) p sample.value
(double) $14 = 0.029
(lldb) p longAverage
(double) $15 = 0.032
(lldb) p (sample.value > longAverage)
(bool) $16 = false
(lldb) p shortAverage
```

other values

```
(double) $17 = 0.029821
(lldb) p shortWithoutFirstAverage
(double) $18 = 0.029802
```

it looks like it is evaluated as

if ((sample.value > shortAverage) > (shortWithoutFirstAverage > longAverage)) {

**but how to achieve the desired if statement?, so that it is true, that (sample.value > shortAverage > shortWithoutFirstAverage > longAverage)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check the expressions like this-

```
if (sample.value > shortAverage > shortWithoutFirstAverage > longAverage)
```

Use-

```
if ( (shortWithoutFirstAverage > longAverage) && (shortAverage > shortWithoutFirstAverage) && (sample.value > shortAverage) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain binary operators such as `>` like this in C and related languages.

Change:

```
if (sample.value > shortAverage > shortWithoutFirstAverage > longAverage) {
```

to:

```
if (sample.value > shortAverage &&
    shortAverage > shortWithoutFirstAverage &&
    shortWithoutFirstAverage > longAverage) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in this way:

`if ((sample.value > shortAverage) && (shortAverage > shortWithoutFirstAverage) && (shortWithoutFirstAverage > longAverage))`